# Accessing private GitHub repos in Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, github, multibranch-pipeline

I have Jenkins setup with both SSH and a private token - so it can access a "Git" private repo quite happily, and via the Config screen it can set the hooks. The pipeline itself works perfectly well outside this issue.

My issue is where I want to create a "GitHub" source so that it can support the extra features (including automatic webhook and reporting back), but all the repos are private, so nothing is showing up when trying to add it.

I have token credentials setup (secret key for Jenkins config, user + pass/token for Branch Sources) - they are setup from a user with full access to the repos (the same user providing ssh access to the "Git" source). The token works correctly for the main Jenkins config.

**Issue:** The GitHub source recognises the Owner name correctly, but the Repository dropdown remains stubbornly empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the token also requires the "user:email" permission to work properly, once this is added then things work. It is significantly easier to add via the Blue Ocean plugin and its wizard however.

Comment: now it's not an option, blueocean is deprecated and not advised to use for any reason except visualization

Comment: @Limmy Reference for people reading - https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin#blue-ocean-status :-)